# Qprogressbar does not attach in qtreewidget of mainwindow when done through global pointer variable of mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt

I have function in which data and qprogress bar is inserted in qtreewidget. When the function calls from  mainwindow constructor it works fine but when the function calls from global pointer variable data is inserted in all respective column but progress not attached to the respective column of treewidget.My code is -

```
MainWindow *mainw; //global variable  

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 

:QMainWindow(parent),ui(newUi::MainWindow)

{

 ui->setupUi(this);
 filltree();// work fine
}

void MainWindow::filltree()
{

  QProgressBar *prgbar=new QProgressBar();

  cities1 = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);

  cities1->settext(0,RAM1);

  cities->settext(1,RAM2);

  ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(cities1,3,prgbar);

}

void funglobal()

{

mainw->filltree(); //problem is here progressbar not attached to column of row of treewidget 

}
```

Comment: didn't you mama teach you to never use global variables? Also always describe what problem you are trying to solve. Here you have described crappy solution of mysterious problem and this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Basically  funglobal function calls automaticaly .I wanted to  call filltreeitem() whenever funglobal function call.Is there any other way to resolve this

Comment: this is still is not a problem you are trying to resolve, but the way you are trying to resolve it. Try starting from something like this: "As a end user I want to see updated progress bar when ... some data .... ." and continue explain problem step by step until you reach your attempt to solve this problem which doesn't work.